# How to get individual table row using data-index attribute to get the value of its <td> when clicking on the row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I need to be able to click on a row in my table and return the value of its `<td>` to the user. I'm using the Bootstrap Table cdn to construct my table. This dynamically creates a table body and table rows with data-index attributes.

I want to be able to click on an individual row and get the values of its cells.
This is the current click event that I have set up.

```js
let data = []
$("#table").on("click", function() {
  const $ths = $(this).find("tr");
  $.each($ths, function() {
    const innerData = [];
    $(this).find("td").each(function() {
      innerData.push($(this).text().trim());
    });
    data.push(innerData);
  })
  console.log(data)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table'>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-index="0">
      <td>ACB</td>
      <td>1540</td>
      <td>0784</td>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="1">
      <td>ACB</td>
      <td>1559</td>
      <td>0784</td>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="2">
      <td>ACB</td>
      <td>2095</td>
      <td>0784</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="3">
      <td>ADH</td>
      <td>0001</td>
      <td>0347</td>
      <td>S</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="4">
      <td>ADH</td>
      <td>1075</td>
      <td>0347</td>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="5">
      <td>ADH</td>
      <td>0001</td>
      <td>0347</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="6">
      <td>ADH</td>
      <td>1076</td>
      <td>0347</td>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="7">
      <td>AHG</td>
      <td>2136</td>
      <td>0657</td>
      <td>W</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="8">
      <td>AHG</td>
      <td>1037</td>
      <td>0657</td>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="9">
      <td>AHG</td>
      <td>I013</td>
      <td>0657</td>
      <td>W</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This click event will push all of the tr's into the data array. Like this

```
[
    [],
    [
        "ACB",
        "1559",
        "0784",
        "E"
    ],
    [
        "ACB",
        "2095",
        "0784",
        "A"
    ],
    [
        "ACB",
        "1540",
        "0784",
        "E"
    ],
    [
        "ADH",
        "1076",
        "0347",
        "E"
    ],
    [
        "ADH",
        "0001",
        "0347",
        "S"
    ],
    [
        "ADH",
        "0001",
        "0347",
        "A"
    ],
    [
        "ADH",
        "1075",
        "0347",
        "E"
    ],
    [
        "AHG",
        "2136",
        "0657",
        "W"
    ],
    [
        "AHG",
        "1038",
        "0657",
        "E"
    ],
    [
        "AHG",
        "I013",
        "0657",
        "W"
    ]
]
```

I want to be able to get the individual td values when I click on a specific row and push them into the array one at a time, not all at once. Any advice on how to achieve this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're using the Bootstrap Table plugin to create the table, why not use the original data you're constructing the table from, rather than recreating the data from the table?

Comment: I moved my answer to the dupe. Please delete this since it is a dupe